# ListFragment only showing first item in Fragment View with ExpandableListadpater

Tags: fragment, expandablelistadapter

I have one fragment with parent and child items. But expandable list only shows the first item in parent list

The problem is that the list view only shows the first item.it contains 3 items, so the listview should show 3 list. Did I miss anything? thanks a lot.

My fragment is

```
    public class FragmentChapters extends ListFragment {
    
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
        View view;
        Context context;
        public FragmentChapters() {
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chapters, container, false);
    
            return view;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) getListView();
    
            prepareListData();
            context=getActivity();
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(context, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    
            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
  private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }

}
```

My Expandable lisAdpter is

```
[public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

My outupt show this Screen. Only one item listed in fragment.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUiQC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

All is good , Data is actually loading to the expandable list view. Issue is with the layout. You can see the data if you give a fixed height to your Expandable list view. Adjust  height of the parent layout (or NestedScrollView) of the view which you used to replace the fragment into your activity.